# Emacs lisp, how to dynamically create quoted expression including special chars like `?1`?

Tags: debugging, emacs

I would like to dynamically create a list of chars to use with `read-char-choice`. From this [answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/32248/how-to-write-a-function-with-an-interactive-choice-of-the-value-of-the-argument) of similar question, how to construct the list programmatically with unquoted values as choices, `?1` with a function. The function that I ended up is

```
(defun prompt-list (name-list)
  "docstring"
  (let ((names name-list)
        (name-num 1)
        (choice-list (list)))
    (dolist (x names)
      (add-to-list 'choice-list
                   `(,name-num ;; in that part how to create the ?1, ?2 but dynamically
                     ,x (lambda () (setq project-headers x))))
      (setq name-num (+ 1 name-num)))
    choice-list))
```

when I try to run it it returns error : `Format specifier doesn’t match argument type`.
In my understanding it need a char type, so my question is how to produce char types programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`?1` is the read syntax for the character `'1'`, which has the integer value 49. You can use the read syntax to initialize your `name-num` variable, rather than using the integer 1:

```
(defun prompt-list (name-list)
  "docstring"
  (let ((names name-list)
        (name-num ?1)
        (choice-list (list)))
    (dolist (x names)
      (add-to-list 'choice-list `(,name-num
                                  ,x (lambda () (setq project-headers ',x)))
                   t)
      (setq name-num (+ 1 name-num)))
    choice-list))
```

A couple of things to note:

1. You want the use `,x` when setting `project-headers`, not just `x`, as the latter won't be valid by the time the `lambda` is invoked.
2. You want to append to `choice-list` as you build it, which is what the final `t` argument to `add-to-list` above does, otherwise your `read-char-choice` prompt will be in reverse order.